# Grails spring security not working: Local Auth (No LDAP)

Tags: grails, spring-security, ldap

I am trying to log in with a database user I created in the Bootstrap file, but I keep getting the error: Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password.

I've checked various tutorials working with the 2.4 plugin of spring, and I really don't know what I'm missing.

Please help me...I need to figure this out soon :S

My models are:

User:

```
class User {

transient springSecurityService

String username
String password
boolean enabled = true
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired

static transients = ['springSecurityService']


static constraints = {
    username blank: false, unique: true
    password blank: false
}

static mapping = {
    password column: '`password`'
}

Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
    UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
}

def beforeInsert() {
    encodePassword()
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    if (isDirty('password')) {
        encodePassword()
    }
}

String toString()
{
    return username
}

protected void encodePassword() {
    password = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
}
```

}

Role:

class Role {

```
String authority

static mapping =
{
    cache true
}

static constraints = 
{
    authority blank: false, unique: true
}
```

}

UserRole:

```
class UserRole implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

User user
Role role

boolean equals(other) {
    if (!(other instanceof UserRole)) {
        return false
    }

    other.user?.id == user?.id &&
    other.role?.id == role?.id
}

int hashCode() {
    def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
    if (user) builder.append(user.id)
    if (role) builder.append(role.id)
    builder.toHashCode()
}

static UserRole get(long userId, long roleId) {
    UserRole.where {
        user == User.load(userId) &&
        role == Role.load(roleId)
    }.get()
}

static boolean exists(long userId, long roleId) {
    UserRole.where {
        user == User.load(userId) &&
        role == Role.load(roleId)
    }.count() > 0
}

static UserRole create(User user, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
    def instance = new UserRole(user: user, role: role)
    instance.save(flush: flush, insert: true)
    instance
}

static boolean remove(User u, Role r, boolean flush = false) {
    if (u == null || r == null) return false

    int rowCount = UserRole.where {
        user == User.load(u.id) &&
        role == Role.load(r.id)
    }.deleteAll()

    if (flush) { UserRole.withSession { it.flush() } }

    rowCount > 0
}

static void removeAll(User u, boolean flush = false) {
    if (u == null) return

    UserRole.where {
        user == User.load(u.id)
    }.deleteAll()

    if (flush) { UserRole.withSession { it.flush() } }
}

static void removeAll(Role r, boolean flush = false) {
    if (r == null) return

    UserRole.where {
        role == Role.load(r.id)
    }.deleteAll()

    if (flush) { UserRole.withSession { it.flush() } }
}

static constraints = {
    role validator: { Role r, UserRole ur ->
        if (ur.user == null) return
        boolean existing = false
        UserRole.withNewSession {
            existing = UserRole.exists(ur.user.id, r.id)
        }
        if (existing) {
            return 'userRole.exists'
        }
    }
}

static mapping = {
    id composite: ['role', 'user']
    version false
}
```

}

Config File:

grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'co.edu.uelbosque.UnBosqueInscripciones.modelos.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'co.edu.uelbosque.UnBosqueInscripciones.modelos.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'co.edu.uelbosque.UnBosqueInscripciones.modelos.Role'

Boostrap File:

```
class BootStrap {

def init = { servletContext ->
    def rol1 = new Role(authority:'ROLE_USER')
    def rol2 = new Role(authority:'ROLE_ADMIN')

    rol1.save(flush:true)
    rol2.save(flush:true)

    def us2 = new User(username:'testUser', password:'1234')

    us2.save(flush:true)

    new UserRole(user:us2, role:rol2).save(flush:true)
}
def destroy = {
}
```

}

Plugins used (security plugin 2.0.RC):

```
plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

    //Plugins adicionales
    compile ":mysql-connectorj:5.1.22.1"
    compile ":spring-security-ldap:2.0-RC4"
    compile ":simple-captcha:1.0.0"

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"


    // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
    //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
    //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
    //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
    //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
}
```